# What is best way to move an Object in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, game-physics

I just wrote a simple app to test moving a graphic Texture by the input given from the user. There is a circle png in the middle of the screen and if the user touches it, the circle will follow the user's finger. 
Here is code:

```
private int HEIGHT, WIDTH;
private Circle circle;
private final int RADIUS = 256;
private boolean circleTouched, firstClick;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture b1;

@Override
public void create()
{
    WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    circleTouched = false;
    firstClick = true;
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    b1 = new Texture("b1.png");
    circle = new Circle(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, RADIUS);
}

@Override
public void render()
{
    //Logic
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched())
    {
        if (circleTouched)
        {
            circle.x += Gdx.input.getDeltaX();
            circle.y += Gdx.input.getDeltaY();
        }
        else if (isCircleTouched(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), circle) && firstClick)
        {
            circleTouched = true;
        }
        else
        {
            firstClick = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        circleTouched = false;
        firstClick = true;
    }

    //Drawing
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(b1, circle.x - circle.radius, HEIGHT - circle.y - circle.radius);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose()
{
    super.dispose();
}

private boolean isCircleTouched(int x, int y, Circle c)
{
    return ((x - c.x) * (x - c.x) + (y - c.y) * (y - c.y)) <= (c.radius * c.radius);
}
```

1. Is this a good way to move objects (if I have 15 objects like this app performance still ll be good?)
2. Is it possible to use function draw not from a bottom-left corner but from top-left? I have to subtract height every time when I draw.
3. My png is 512x512 how I can set the dimension to draw texture with a given dimension?

EDIT 1. firstClick can be replaced by Gdx.input.justTouched()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't find 15 objects that much, especially as you are only using 2d textures and some simple math. However, when you code base grows you should think about refactoring it and move the logic to dedicated classes.
2. The `draw` function always uses the bottom-left corner. But you could use the `Sprite` class which can take origin coordinates: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html
3. If youn don't want to try out the `Sprite` class for this, you can also use the `Texture.getWidth` and `getHeight` methods: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html#getWidth--

When it comes to structuring `libGdx` code I always found `Ashley` quite helpful: https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/wiki/How-to-use-Ashley